# pyspark foreach does not parallelize when applying to a Dataframe that was aggregated (but does on a normal Dataframe)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, foreach, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame in pyspark.
I have one driver and 3 executors/workers.

When I want to apply a function to each row and have it run on one of the 3 executors it works on a normal dataframe but if I have done a groupBy and agg to the dataframe then it all goes on the same executor/worker.

```
data = [('James','Smith','apples','a'),('James','Smith','oranges','b'),('James','Smith','lemons','a'),('Anna','Rose','apples','a'),('Anna','Rose','lemons','b'), ('Robert','Williams','oranges','v'), ]
columns = ["firstname","lastname","fuits","letter"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = columns)
df.show()

+---------+--------+-------+------+
|firstname|lastname|  fuits|letter|
+---------+--------+-------+------+
|    James|   Smith| apples|     a|
|    James|   Smith|oranges|     b|
|    James|   Smith| lemons|     a|
|     Anna|    Rose| apples|     a|
|     Anna|    Rose| lemons|     b|
|   Robert|Williams|oranges|     v|
+---------+--------+-------+------+

dfagg = df.groupBy("firstname","lastname").agg(functions.collect_list("fuits"), functions.collect_list("letter"))

dfagg.show()

+---------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+
|firstname|lastname| collect_list(fuits)|collect_list(letter)|
+---------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    James|   Smith|[apples, oranges,...|           [a, b, a]|
|     Anna|    Rose|    [lemons, apples]|              [b, a]|
|   Robert|Williams|           [oranges]|                 [v]|
+---------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I then apply the foreach with a simple function :

```
# Foreach example
def f(x): 
    print(x)
    print(' ===== > this is in the simple foreach')
        
def f2(x): 
    print(x)
    print(' ===== > this is in the aggregated foreach')

# foreach applied to the normal dataframe
df.foreach(f)

# foreach applied to the dataframe that was aggregated
dfagg.foreach(f2)
```

- For the normal dataframe and foreach I get the expected outcome:
  The prints of the 6 rows are distributed on the 3 executors/workers

On the executor 1

```
Row(firstname='James', lastname='Smith', fuits='lemons', letter='a')
 ===== > this is in the simple foreach
Row(firstname='Anna', lastname='Rose', fuits='apples', letter='a')
 ===== > this is in the simple foreach
```

On the executor 2

```
Row(firstname='Anna', lastname='Rose', fuits='lemons', letter='b')
 ===== > this is in the simple foreach
Row(firstname='Robert', lastname='Williams', fuits='oranges', letter='v')
 ===== > this is in the simple foreach
```

On the executor 3

```
Row(firstname='James', lastname='Smith', fuits='apples', letter='a')
 ===== > this is in the simple foreach
Row(firstname='James', lastname='Smith', fuits='oranges', letter='b')
 ===== > this is in the simple foreach
```

- But for the foreach on the aggregated dataframe:
  **Everything goes to the same executor/worker**

```
Row(firstname='James', lastname='Smith', collect_list(fuits)=['lemons', 'apples', 'oranges'], collect_list(letter)=['a', 'a', 'b'])
 ===== > this is in the aggregated foreach
Row(firstname='Anna', lastname='Rose', collect_list(fuits)=['apples', 'lemons'], collect_list(letter)=['a', 'b'])
 ===== > this is in the aggregated foreach
Row(firstname='Robert', lastname='Williams', collect_list(fuits)=['oranges'], collect_list(letter)=['v'])
 ===== > this is in the aggregated foreach
```

**How can I distribute the function on each row to the 3 executors ?**

I need to work on an aggregated dataframe and performe quite long functions on each aggregated row, so it needs to be distributed otherwise it takes too long.

I have tried with more data to see if there was a min amount of data -> no change

Both dataframes are of the same type

```
print( 'Type of df : ', type(df) )
print( 'Type of dfagg : ', type(dfagg) )

Type of df :  <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
Type of dfagg :  <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have data skew. I can't think of why else all data is ending up on one node.

If you are using a recent version spark 3.0.(You could use [adaptive query](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#adaptive-query-execution) to help automagically adjust your shuffle partitions.)

If you aren't so luck (to be on spark 3.0) you could try [`distribute by`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-distribute-by.html), set an appropriate shuffle partitions value or [repartition](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-performance-tuning-groupBy-aggregation.html).  This should redistribute the data hopefully in a way that enables you to use all of your cluster.